# print vector as with "and" in \Sexpr{}

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

Consider this simple vector:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

`\Sexpr{x}` will print in LaTeX `1,2,3,4,5` but I often I need to report some vectors in text as a human,  including "and" before the last number.

I tried todo automatically with this function:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
nicevector <- function(x){
    a <- head(x,length(x)-1)
    b <- tail(x,1)
    cat(a,sep=", ");cat(" and ");cat(b)}
nicevector(x)
```

That seem to work in the console `\Sexpr{nicevector(x)}` but failed miserably in the .Rnw file (while \Sexpr{x} works). Some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `knitr::combine_words(x)`.

Using `cat()` is only for its side-effect: printing in the console. `cat()` won't *return* a character string, so you won't see anything in the output. By comparison, `knitr::combine_words()` returns a character string.

Comment: I did not remember knitr having this nice function and I started to [reinvent the wheel](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*hfYJXXcFiNGbcyzcgkSAiQ.png) ... Thank you very much for knitr.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a function for this in `glue` package

```
glue::glue_collapse(1:4, ",", last = " and ")
#> 1, 2, 3 and 4
```

See [help of function](https://glue.tidyverse.org/reference/glue_collapse.html)